# Set horizontal center to a textView which is in relativeLyout into a linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using a linear layout in order to place my different element in my view. In this one, I put a relative layout to set horizontal center to a textView. this my view's code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.selectionModele.seguin_android.SelectionModeleActivity"
android:background="@drawable/selection_modele_fond"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selection_modele_textView_famille"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/selection_news_viewPager"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_height="308dp">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But when i'm launching my application, my textView isn't center, and i don't why ?
How can i solve the problem please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `android:gravity="center"` to your `TextView` in xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/selection_modele_textView_famille"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```